# Using datagrid values in a switch statement

Tags: c#, datagrid, switch-statement

In my program I have a datagridview table `c_tbl` which gets data from a SQL Server and populates the datagridview. I have a for loop running through each row. Now I have a switch statement that should check each row and get the value so I can compare it and add other data in that row.

This is what it looks like

```
for(int i=0; i<c_tbl.rows.count; i++){
      switch("this is where i need the argument that will check the row and column value)
      {
         case "string value that gets compared"
                  //add in values to column on same row. 
       }
}
```

I originally had something like

```
switch(c_tbl.Column[0][i])
```

but it's not working.

Comment: Please clearly define ***it's not working*** - that's **not** a really helpful "error" message.....

Comment: I posted what the error was below. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the [DataTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) like this:

```
foreach (DataRow row in c_tbl.Rows)
{
    foreach (DataColumn col in c_tbl.Columns)
    {
        switch (row[col].ToString())
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i get another error saying it cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Data.DataColumn'

Comment: That word thanks. I had an error in a different part of the code. Thanks again.

Comment: I'm glad that it works. If it truly answered your question, please accept it as the answer.